# Why is string with dollar sign not working in javascript function?

Tags: javascript

why doesn't the word apple doesn't appear using function inside function . I tried many times with different words but not working
the result is always
it is   ${fuit}

```
const firstfunction=(fuit)=>{
    const gettingbrackets='it is   ${fuit}'
    console.log (gettingbrackets)
}
firstfunction('apple')
```

Answer (score 7):

You have used the wrong quotation marks. You need to use backtick ``` `` ``` character instead of single `'` (or double `"`) quotes. For more details please read the docs about [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) carefully

```js
const firstfunction=(fuit)=>{
    const gettingbrackets=`it is   ${fuit}`
    console.log (gettingbrackets)
}
firstfunction('apple')
```